# Zero inflated model problem: system is computationally singular

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, zero-inflation, singular-matrix

I'm using R.After getting an error asking me to provide starting values for a glm (poisson family), I took a look at my data and realized I had quite a bit of zeroes. So, I tried zeroinfl from pscl. I got the "computationally singular" error, so I tried dist="negbin". Same error. I looked at my data via with(bytype, table(Events, Type)) and with(bytype, table(Events, Generation)). It looks like my data is wonky. But I don't know how to deal with that. I think I need to cut part of it out, but the easy attempts (group with most zeroes) didn't work.

First, my basic model: Events ~ Generation*Type + offset(log(Population))

Second, data summaries:

by Generation:

```
Events Familicide Home.Intruder Rampage Sabotage School Vehicular Workplace
     0         49            88      59      103     91       111        94
     1         40            21      37       10     11         1        17
     2         18             4      11        0     10         1         2
     3          4             0       5        0      1         0         0
     4          2             0       1        0      0         0         0
```

by Event Type:

```
Events Missionary Lost  GI Silent Boomers   X
     0        139  103 110    103     106  34
     1         24   17  15     29      34  18
     2          4    5   1     13      17   6
     3          1    1   0      1       3   4
     4          0    0   0      1       1   1
```

Due to posting length limits, my entire data won't fit. I hope this is enough to go on

Added on edit: It might matter that "Generation" is ordinal and I've set contrasts to c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"). I don't know if that matters in this case.

Comment: Came up with an alternative model, same expression but the levels of "Generation" are integers (1-6). (Null Deviance 757.95, 790 Df; resid deviance 528.94, 777df). This might actually be more valid, since cultural borders between generations are actually rather fuzzy. We think of them as discrete entities, but the difference between someone born 1960 vs. 1961 usually aren't all that large. Or have I decided to bark up not only the wrong tree but an entirely wrong forest?